# Relevant aspects about real valued functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I am studying a function (a simple real valued function, like $f(x) = 2x$), and I would like to know what are the relevant properties to calculate about it.

I have already studied

- Addition ($f(x + y) = ...$)
- Multiplication ($f(xy) = ...$)
- Derivative
- Primitive

Is there anything else that I am overlooking?

Comment: This is quite vague. Is there anything concrete you can tell us about?

Answer (score 0):

As noted, this is vague, and really depends on your context. Maybe you want all roots of the function? Or perhaps only the real ones? Rational? Integer?

Or maybe you want to know if this function is a bijection? Or perhaps a surjection or injection?

Depending on exactly what you are studying, you may not need any or all of these properties, and more.